# Received json array response from API without brackets

Tags: c#, .net, json, api

I think what I have got is a json response from Rest API called.But all the array fields do not contain [].  When I parse, it give me error.

I had tried JObject.Parse or JsonConvert.DeserializeObject, both of them give me error.  When I added [], it works like a charm.

```
var content= "{'main': {'item': 'item1', 'value': 'value1'}, {'item': 'item2', 'value': 'value2'} }";
```

When I tried:

```
jRoot = JObject.Parse(content);
```

I received

> {"Invalid property identifier character: {. Path 'main', line 1, position 47."}

When I tried:

```
var = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<mainOBJ>(content);
```

I received

> {"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: }. Path 'main', line 1, position 7."}

Comment: You're trying to parse something that isn't valid JSON (however similar) with a JSON parser. Other than hacky solutions, the best advice would be to contact the API maintainers and get them to fix it.

Comment: What does https://jsonlint.com say about that 'JSON'?

Comment: That's not JSON. No JSON serializer would create this string. No parser will be able to parse it either. Looks like the REST API authors tried to create JSON strings by hand instead of using a JSON serializer

Comment: You can't *assume* that `main` is an array either. What if the forgotten part was a `main2:` tag before the second dictionary? It could be that `main` is an array of items, or that `main` is one of two attributes in the root dictionary.

Comment: please set my answer as answer of this question

Answer (score 3):

Your correct json format must be like this:

```
var content= "{'main': [{'item': 'item1', 'value': 'value1'}, {'item': 'item2', 'value': 'value2'} ]}";
```